# Is it possible to entangle particles for their path?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

In the figure below, you have a source of entangled particles that then sends these particles in opposite directions.

[image]

Each stream of particles heads towards a double slit with a detector screen beyond the slits.  Is it possible to entangle these particles with respect to their path such that if a particle goes through slit A then its entangled pair must go through slit D, and if a particle goes trough slit B, then its entangled pair must go through slit C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the configuration you've drawn, no, that won't be possible.

**If** you modify the source so that it has the capability to point independently at slit A (resp. B, C, D) without illuminating the slit B (resp. A, D, C) in the process, though, then the answer is **yes**, that's a perfectly possible state. In this form (and unless you perform some form of quantum-eraser experiment and look at coincidence counts between the two screens) neither screen will present an interference pattern.

Entanglement in path is one of the main standard ways to produce entangled photons. For examples in practice, try e.g. [this search](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q="path+entanglement").

Comment: If you set up the experiment in the way that you suggest, then is it still possible to get and interference pattern on the screen if the which path information is not recorded?

Comment: @kishdude No, neither screen will show an interference pattern - the which-way information *is* indeed recorded, on the other photon.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, Could you give a link where the fringe visibility  is deduced from the properties of the emitted pair (in the tensor product space) ? thanks